# grab brush not working properly

Tags: sculpting

it should grab it and move it to the right

[image]

help
it is doing this instead of this i resetted the brush and still happening what do i can do?
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: my file is 31 mb , blender paste is 30mb how can i compress it? or similar

Comment: or use another platform like workupload

Comment: ok im on it https://workupload.com/file/KF7B3r2pfX5

Comment: workupload.com/file/KF7B3r2pfX5 tried with quad sphere, f9  , subdivision 2, extrude on z axis 1 time the 4 center faces of top , multires modifier to 3 , tried with round cube, still got the same error, resetted the brush and still getting the problem, its a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *Cavity* option (not sure why it messes up your sculpt though):

[image]

Comment: you are a master, thank you, solved!!! and sent extra hamburguer for u, tnx

Comment: where do i report this bug to dev team?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug actually, but I don't understand why it acts like that, Cavity should allow the brush to act on the mesh except its cavities (concave areas)